# If my pipelined function calls a stored procedure which returns the data to be pipelined, does this defeat the purpose?

Tags: oracle, plsql, pipeline

I'm working with Pipelined functions which pipe results to a reporting tool.  However the data to be piped is obtained by a call to a stored procedure, and returned to the function in an output parameter of type cursor.
I'm questioning whether there is any point in "piping the data" as it seems to me that there would be a bottleneck at the stored procedure, which would have to complete before the piping can begin.
I'm relatively new to Oracle so unfamiliar with design patterns.

Comment: You said that the "data ... is obtained by a call to a stored procedure" but then say it "returned to the function in an output parameter of type cursor". Which is it? If it is returning a ref cursor, it's not returning data. If it's returning data (through a collection type variable), then it's not returning a cursor.

Comment: If the procedure is simply opening and returning a ref cursor and the function does the fetching, then your piping is still providing benefit. You are avoiding having to collect all the rows in memory and further allows consuming SQL to feed rows to the next plan step as they arrive, which is particularly helpful when using parallel slaves (so the next set can start working while the first is still producing rows)

Comment: There isn't necessarily a bottleneck at the stored procedure, as a cursor is a specification for a result set to be streamed and not a container full of data. Can't the reporting tool call the procedure directly though?

Comment: @PaulW and William Thanks for these answers.  I think what I'm understanding is that the Stored Procedure should complete quickly if all it does is create a cursor i.e. it never retrieves the data.  On the other hand, if my output variable was a table type variable (collection type variable) then it would be "filled" by the stored procedure, before control were returned to the function.  Am I right with my first assumption that the Function cannot start to pipeline anything until the Stored Procedure has completed its work?  Many thanks to both of you, for your thoughtful answers.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I'm not sure if the reporting tool (Business Objects) can call a stored procedure.  I would be surprised if it couldn't, but I will check.  What I've seen here is that every time this reporting tool is used, a wrapper pipeline function has been created.  I don't know why this is, and no-one here likes to call into question how things are done.  If it did call the SP directly, is some pipeline benefit lost (as it seems we can only pipe from the function)?

Comment: Basically, yes.